# Change button attribute on hide/show canvas

Tags: javascript, html, button, canvas, toggle

Whilst learning, i keep going back over what i have done to understand it properly, make changes and improvements. At the moment, i am going over my hide/show function.

I have 3 buttons which controls the visibility of their respective canvases.
My code did look like this:

```
    function toggleRedDot(){
        document.getElementById('btnRed').click(); {
            if(canvas.style.visibility=='hidden'){
                canvas.style.visibility='visible';
                btnRed.style.color='Red';
            }else{
                canvas.style.visibility='hidden';
                btnRed.style.color='Black';
            }
        }
    };
```

Both the Green and Blue toggle functions are identical except for the button color. My project actually has 7 buttons and canvases. I'm trying to put all these functions into 1, and this is now what i have:

```
    function toggle_visibility(id) 
    {
        var ele = document.getElementById(id);
        if (ele.style.visibility == 'hidden')
        {
            ele.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else 
        {
            ele.style.visibility = 'hidden';                
        }
    }
```

I have been unable to work out how to now change the corresponding button color attribute. The idea is that the button will look 'on' when canvas is visible and the color reverts to Black when 'off'.

I also need the answer to be in just javascript please, as this is what i am learning.
I am also hoping to do a similar sort of thing to my drawDots function as they also differ in class, and location. Thank you.

I made a snippet:

```js
  var canvas = document.getElementById('redDot');
  var ctxR = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var canvas1 = document.getElementById('greenDot');
  var ctxG = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  var canvas2 = document.getElementById('blueDot');
  var ctxB = canvas2.getContext('2d');

  var cw = canvas.width;
  var ch = canvas.height;

  drawDots();

  function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(id);
    if (ele.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
      ele.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
      ele.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  }

  function drawDots() {

    //   Red Dot
    ctxR.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctxR.save();
    ctxR.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2);
    ctxR.beginPath();
    ctxR.arc(-50, 0, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctxR.closePath();
    ctxR.fillStyle = 'Red';
    ctxR.fill();
    ctxR.restore();

    //   Green Dot
    ctxG.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctxG.save();
    ctxG.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2);
    ctxG.beginPath();
    ctxG.arc(0, 0, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctxG.closePath();
    ctxG.fillStyle = 'Green';
    ctxG.fill();
    ctxG.restore();

    //   Blue Dot
    ctxB.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctxB.save();
    ctxB.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2);
    ctxB.beginPath();
    ctxB.arc(50, 0, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctxB.closePath();
    ctxB.fillStyle = 'Blue';
    ctxB.fill();
    ctxB.restore();
  };
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.red {
  color: Red;
}
.green {
  color: Green;
}
.blue {
  color: Blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="btnWrapper">
  <button id="btnRed" class="red" title="Toggle Red Dot" onclick="toggle_visibility('redDot')">&#9737;</button>
  <button id="btnGreen" class="green" title="Toggle Green Dot" onclick="toggle_visibility('greenDot')">&#9737;</button>
  <button id="btnBlue" class="blue" title="Toggle Blue Dot" onclick="toggle_visibility('blueDot')">&#9737;</button>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="redDot" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
  <canvas id="greenDot" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
  <canvas id="blueDot" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say there are more than 3 colours I have written an example that will simplify the creation of multiply buttons.

The buttons and canvases are uniquely identified by their colour so I use the colours to query the DOM for references and use a function closure (forEach callback function) to hold the references for when needed.

I would have actually created the buttons and canvas inside that function as well but you may want it in the html so there will still be so tedious markup to create when adding more buttons.

Rather than manipulate the element styles I have add the DOM classes, `.black` for the button, and `.hide` and `.show` for the canvas. So all that is needed is to set the element's class name rather than their styles. Will make it easier if you have a complicated set of styles to switch between.

```js
"Red,Green,Blue".split(",").forEach((col,i)=>{
    var col_l = col.toLowerCase();
    var ctx = document.getElementById(col_l+ 'Dot').getContext('2d');
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn"+col);
    btn.title ="Toggle "+col +" Dot" ;
    btn.className = col_l ;
    ctx.canvas.className = "show";
    var cw = ctx.canvas.width;
    var ch = ctx.canvas.height;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.fillStyle = col;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cw/2 -50 + i * 50, ch/2, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    function toggle(){  // this function has closure over col_l ,ctx, and btn
        if (ctx.canvas.className == 'hide') {
           ctx.canvas.className = "show";
           btn.className = col_l ;
        }else{
           ctx.canvas.className = "hide";
           btn.className = "black";
        }
    }        
    btn.addEventListener("click",toggle);
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
 /* for canvas hide and show */
.hide {
    visibility : hidden;
}
.show {
    visibility : visible;
}
.red {
  color: Red;
}
.green {
  color: Green;
}
.blue {
  color: Blue;
}
.black {  /* "black" colour button */
  color: Black;
}
```

```html
<!-- removed most of the stuff that is better added in code. -->
<div id="btnWrapper">  
  <button id="btnRed">&#9737;</button> 
  <button id="btnGreen">&#9737;</button>
  <button id="btnBlue">&#9737;</button>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="redDot" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
  <canvas id="greenDot" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
  <canvas id="blueDot" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: This is error from IE11: "message": "Syntax error","filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js","lineno": 48,"colno": 53 And from Safari: "message": "Script error.","filename": "","lineno": 0,"colno": undefined I thought it was to do with the i, so I put var i=0; but it didn't work either.

Comment: @Cyb3rMann Yes that is because IE11 does not support arrow functions. Just replace `(col,i)=>` with `function(col,i)` or use a something like babel.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a little more sense, i was reading that as 'equal to or more than' :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of ways to approach this. The way I chose simply passes the id of the button along with the id of the canvas to `toggle_visibility`. I also added a small object so that the color for a button can be looked up via a button id.

Things to consider in the future:

- Because DOM reads/writes are somewhat expensive, consider reading the DOM once and storing the elements on the JS side
- Consider using `addEventListener` from JS instead of `onclick` in HTML

  - Your markup will be cleaner
  - You won't have to pass parameters like `btnRed` and `redDot` because event listeners receive an event which knows which element fired the event
- Instead of manipulating the visibility/color directly in the JS, have a CSS class (or classes) that do what you want and just change the class.

Good luck! :)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('redDot');
var ctxR = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('greenDot');
var ctxG = canvas1.getContext('2d');
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('blueDot');
var ctxB = canvas2.getContext('2d');

var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;

drawDots();

var buttonIdToColor = {
  btnRed:   'red',
  btnGreen: 'green',
  btnBlue:  'blue'
};

function toggle_visibility(buttonId, dotId) {
  var button = document.getElementById(buttonId)
  var dot    = document.getElementById(dotId);

  if (dot.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
    dot.style.visibility = 'visible';
    button.style.color   = buttonIdToColor[buttonId];
  } else {
    dot.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    button.style.color   = 'black';
  }
}

function drawDots() {

  //      Red Dot
  ctxR.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctxR.save();
  ctxR.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2);
  ctxR.beginPath();
  ctxR.arc(-50, 0, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctxR.closePath();
  ctxR.fillStyle = 'Red';
  ctxR.fill();
  ctxR.restore();

  //      Green Dot
  ctxG.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctxG.save();
  ctxG.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2);
  ctxG.beginPath();
  ctxG.arc(0, 0, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctxG.closePath();
  ctxG.fillStyle = 'Green';
  ctxG.fill();
  ctxG.restore();

  //      Blue Dot
  ctxB.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctxB.save();
  ctxB.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2);
  ctxB.beginPath();
  ctxB.arc(50, 0, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctxB.closePath();
  ctxB.fillStyle = 'Blue';
  ctxB.fill();
  ctxB.restore();
};
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.red {
  color: Red;
}
.green {
  color: Green;
}
.blue {
  color: Blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="btnWrapper">
  <button id="btnRed" class="red" title="Toggle Red Dot" onclick="toggle_visibility('btnRed', 'redDot')">&#9737;</button>
  <button id="btnGreen" class="green" title="Toggle Green Dot" onclick="toggle_visibility('btnGreen', 'greenDot')">&#9737;</button>
  <button id="btnBlue" class="blue" title="Toggle Blue Dot" onclick="toggle_visibility('btnBlue', 'blueDot')">&#9737;</button>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="redDot" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
  <canvas id="greenDot" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
  <canvas id="blueDot" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Storing elements on js side. Do you mean things like `onclick` in the html? If so i have a few more of these like `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`. I looked at `eventListeners` but thought it was a bit over my head at the time. The more examples i come across, the more i'm picking it up, so i will look into that again. The last point is what i was trying to do. I gave the button a class and I was trying to use something like `document.getElementById(id).className`. Can i still do something like that, since the colours have already been declared in the class, instead of `var buttonIdToColor`?

Comment: Looks like my last question has been answered below. I used your example but changed `dotId` and `dot` to `canvasId` and `canvas`. Many thanks.

Comment: I'd say for now, just keep doing what you're doing, but keep these ideas in the back of your mind. @Blindman67 posted a great answer that encompasses all of the suggestion that I made (minimize DOM access, bind event handlers from the JS side, and use CSS classes instead of directly manipulating styles on elements). It probably won't all make sense now, but refer back every once in awhile and it will eventually be totally clear. Cheers! :)